# language c, compile time error multiple unsequenced modifications [-Werror, -Wunsequenced]

Tags: c

Here is the defintion of my function:

```
char *strsub(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len){
   blabla
   blabla
   while (len > 0)
   {
      len--;
      cpy[start++] = s[start++];
   }
}
```

When I try to compile I get this error:

> error : multiple unsecquenced modifications to start -Werror , -Wunsequenced

I don't understand that error at all.

Comment: Well, that's fair enough.  Neither I, not your compiler, understand 'cpy[start++] = s[start++]' :((

Answer (score 5):

```
cpy[start++] = s[start++];
```

In this you modify `start` more than once without an intervening sequence point. This is *undefined behaviour*. Your compiler helpfully points that out.

If you want to copy the bytes from one location to another you probably don't want to modify `start` twice anyway. So, do:

```
while (len > 0)
{
   len--
   cpy[start] = s[start];
   start++;
}
```

Please read:

[Undefined behaviour and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

[A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)

[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

for more informationn on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

Is this

```
cpy[start++] = s[start++];
```

supposed to increment `start` once or twice? While you might know the answer, the compiler scratched its head.

There might be languages where this has a defined result (usually by order of evaluation from left to right), but C is not one of them (it's *undefined behavior*).

The word **unsequenced** in the error message refers to the C language concept of **sequence points**. In the shown expression there is only *one* sequence point -- the semicolon. But there are two post-increments. Which one should be executed first? C leaves this open^Wundefined.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from `C11`, chapter §6.5.16, *Assignment operators*,

> [...] The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is
>   sequenced **after the value computations of the left and right operands. The evaluations of
>   the operands are unsequenced.**

That means, in your code,

```
cpy[start++] = s[start++];
```

you're making attempt to modify the value of `start` more than once without having a sequence point in between, which is plain wrong and will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).